# Query recurring payment profiles via PayPal API

Tags: paypal

When in Paypal under Basic search I can get an overview of all recurring payment profiles created / canceled via 'Subscriptions and agreements' -> 'Recurring payments' -> 'My profiles'. However, in the PayPal API I have only a [TransactionSearch](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_TransactionSearch) call available.

Is it possible to grab this information from the API somewhere?